# Use different data forms inside default grid view in asp.net

Tags: html, sql, asp.net, .net

[image]

I have the above `grid view` where I am using the default one provided by Visual Studio. What I am doing is, via the `server properties` dragging the table and the VS creates the above for me.

However, I want my `category 1` and `category 2` and `category 3` be dropdown lists.

Is there any way to change the default behavior of the grid view?

Answer (score 0):

Use Template Field in the source code inside the grid.
It will look like

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound">
    <Columns>
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="id" DataField="id" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="name" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "category1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblcategory1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("category1") %>' Visible = "false" />
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcategory1" runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and so on.